# How can admin Modify User Profile through DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

Stated in DoucSign API Reference about Modify User Profile ([Link Here](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Modify%20User%20Profile.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____127)):

> The userId specified in the uri must match the authenticated user’s userId and the user must be a member of the account.

How can an admin modifies a normal user's profile through the API?

(Note: the admin does not know the user's password.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the "admin" user (i.e., authenticating user for the API request) must have these settings enabled for their member account within DocuSign:

[image: DS User Permissions]

Then, it's simply a matter of using "Send On Behalf Of" functionality when submitting the API request to modify a user's profile information.  To do so, you simply provide the admin's information in the **X-DocuSign-Authentication** header of the API request (as you do for all other API calls), AND also specify the email address that corresponds to the user account you wish to modify (as the value of the *SendOnBehalfOf* property in the **X-DocuSign-Authentication** header).

For example, consider the following API request (including the **X-Docusign-Authentication** header for the request). In this example, John is the "admin" user (johnDoe@gmail.com) and Jane is the user who's profile will be updated (janeSmith@hotmail.com) -- this request will change Jane's last name to *New_LastName*.

```
PUT https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/201105/users/USER_ID_OF_PROFILE_TO_UPDATE/profile 

X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"johnDoe@gmail.com","Password":"johnsPassword","IntegratorKey":"ABCD-eae5f282-d9f6-47c3-b293-1c4cf78d85kj","SendOnBehalfOf":"janeSmith@hotmail.com" }

{
    "userDetails":{
        "lastName":"New_LastName"
    }
}
```

Within the **X-DocuSign-Authentication** header:

- **Username** represents the email address of the "admin" user account
- **Password** represents the password corresponding to the "admin" user account
- **IntegratorKey** represents the integrator key value that corresponds to the DocuSign account
- **SendOnBehalfOf** represents the *email address corresponding to the user account which the API request will modify*.  This email address should correspond to the same user account represented by the value of **USER_ID_OF_PROFILE_TO_UPDATE** in the API Request URI.

The [DocuSign REST API Guide](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf) contains information about "Send On Behalf Of" functionality.